# highlight if value is duplicate and corresponding cell of all other duplicates is blank

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a list of clients who contacted us. We need to get back to them.

I would like to format if:

1. They appear twice in the list (got that) and
2. We have not gotten back to them in any of their appearances in the list.

For example: if `A5` is duplicated in `A478`, I want sheets to check cell `B478` and format `A5` if `B478` is blank.

Answer (score 0):

*(Please adjust columns and row numbers accordingly)*

The formula you need for column `L` (or even better columns `L` to `M`) is:

```
=and(COUNTIFS($L$11:$L11, $L11)>1, not($M11=""))
```

[image: Conditional formatting duplicates except first when next column not empty]

Please note that the way the formula is structured, **will NOT highlight the first instance**.

If you want the first instance/occurance to be highlighted as well, the formula would be:

```
=and(COUNTIFS($L$11:$L, $L11)>1, not($M11=""))
```